# Variable arguments

Tags: c++, c

Is there a non-boost way to create a function with variable arguments? I know the <del>argument types</del> *number of arguments* and they are <del>usually</del> less then 5, *all of the same type*.

I need to know if there is a way without supplying the argument count or ending the param list with null.

Comment: search for "variadic arguments c++" with google.

Comment: -1 The question phrasing was about something else than the intended question.

Comment: Why is this flagged C? answers would be very different between the two. In C you could do that with macros, but your anti-boost statement seems to indicate that you would not like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For up to 5 arguments all of the same type, simple overloads can do the trick.

For more generality, supporting any number of arguments of the same type, just pass a collection such as a `std::vector`.

For a C++03 technique to build such a collection on the fly in each call, see [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11877917/464581); for C++11, if you do not need to support Visual C++ you can use curly braces initializer lists as actual arguments.

Answer (score 3):

> I know the argument types and they are usually less then 5.

If it is not going to be greater than `5`, then simple overloads *may* do the work. Call the overload which accepts maximam number of arguments from all other overloads accepting less than 5 arguments, or define a worker (internal) function, call this from the overloads.

If possible, you could use default values for some of the parameters, if that helps reducing the number of overloaded functions.

In C++11, you could use [variadic-template](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_template).

Comment: I don't see why to use variadic templates if the argument types are known and - obviously - fixed?

Comment: @JakobS. If the maximum number of arguments truly is not known (the OP said *usually* less than 5), and C++11 variadic templates are a possibility, then I would say that C++11 variadic templates are obviously, hands-down, the best solution.

Comment: Consider the overloads to support 3 arguments. With 5 possible argument types you need 5^3 = 125 overloads, plus the 25 overloads for two arguments, the 5 overloads for 1 argument and the single no argument version; in general, for n arguments that's **(5^(n+1)-1)/4 overloads**. That's a bit too much for my taste.

Comment: @Alf: Hmm.  I think you may have interpreted the question differently (your interpretation may be correct, I don't know).  I, and I think Nawaz, interpreted it as "usually less than 5 arguments, all of a known type" rather than "usually less than 5 argument types".

Comment: @BenjaminLindley What I meant was "usually less than 5 arguments, all of the same type". More exactly they are function pointers.

Comment: @ClaudiuClaw: That changes the *nature* of the question. Just pass an **array**. E.g. a `std::vector`.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: +1 for shedding light on the real situation behind the question. This case is indeed a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Is [cstdarg](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdarg/) what you are looking for? This is the standard C++ way to generate functions with variable numbers of arguments.

Comment: Not sure it's the standard way, it's one way certainly. Has serious limitations in C++ because objects cannot be passed this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able achieve passing variable arguments using [va_list](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stdarg).

Answer (score 0):

As a general C++03 solution you can provide a setter that returns a reference to the object that it's called on, so that it can be called again. And again. And so on, called **chaining**.

It's the same scheme as iostreams use for `operator<<`.

E.g.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void foo( char const s[] )
{
    cout << s << endl;
}

class StringBuilder
{
private:
    string      s_;

    template< class Type >
    string fastStringFrom( Type const& v )
    {
        stringstream stream;
        stream << v;
        return stream.str();
    }

    char const* fastStringFrom( char const* s )
    {
        return s;
    }

    string const& fastStringFrom( string const& s )
    {
        return s;
    }

public:
    template< class Type >
    StringBuilder& operator<<( Type const& v )
    {
        s_ += fastStringFrom( v );
        return *this;                   // Supports chaining.
    }

    operator string const& () const { return s_; }
    operator char const* () const { return s_.c_str(); }
};

int main()
{
    typedef StringBuilder S;

    foo( S() << "6*7 = " << 6*7 << "." );   // Any number of arguments.
}
```

Instead of converting the argument values to text, you just do whatever it is that you need. For example, with a fixed set of possible types you can store the arguments in a collection.

If you do not need to support the Visual C++ compiler, then alternatively you can use a C++11 *variadic template*.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- if you're using C++11 you can use variadic templates, otherwise...
- provide overloads
- use arguments which default to some sentinel values you can recognise ala `f(const T& v1 = missing, const T& v2 = missing, ...) { if (v5 != missing) ...`
- create a simple helper template that can optionally be constructed from the data type and has a bool to track whether it was

  - you may need to support types without default constructors by either using new/delete (simple and safe but slow) or having an aligned buffer you placement `new` into, manually destroy etc. (fiddly and easier to get wrong but faster)
- some compilers have variadic macro support
- if you're prepared to change the calling syntax a bit, you can use any number of things:

  - accept a vector (using a union or variant if the types differ)
  - accept an array (possibly using the `template <size_t N> void f(T (&data)[N]) { ... }` trick to have the compiler provide the array size to you automatically)
  - some kind of lhs object to which extra values can be supplied using an operator such as `operator,` or `operator<<`